# Unable to plot EMA with multiplier factor

Tags: pine-script

The script runs and shows the numeric values but wont plot the second scaled_ema variable line on the chart

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="5 EMA Strategy", overlay=true)

ema = ta.ema(close, 5)
scaled_ema = ema * 1.05

plot(ema, color=color.green, title="EMA")
plot(scaled_ema, color=color.orange, title="Scaled EMA")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there but it is out of your charts price range so you don't see the line. You can actually see its value to confirm.

Either use auto scaling or adjust the price scale manually.

[image]